# Bootstrap dropdown POST

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, post

I have a bootstrap dropdown which is fill with Jquery function.

But when i submit the form:

```html
 
<div class="dropdown">
     <div class="btn-group">
         <button  class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button"  data-toggle="dropdown" >
             Choose basket
             <span class="caret"></span>
         </button>
         <ul  class="dropdown-menu" name="basket" role="menu" id="groupe" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
 
         </ul>
     </div>
 </div>
```

In my action.php `$_POST['basket']` is empty.
This form mustn't be sent with ajax, but just with html "form".

Comment: Your code has no dropdown, `basket` is an unordered list, what value are you expecting ?

Comment: In <ul> I have this exemple <li><a href="#"> A</a></li>. My jQuery function put "A" instead of Choose basket and i want sent A.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample code shows no `<form>` nor any form elements. Giving a `name` attribute to a `ul` doesn't magically make it work as a form element - you'd have to use JavaScript to either fill and submit an invisible form or send the data via AJAX.